# Xamarin Unified API: What about System.Int32 etc. in Shared Code?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I understand that – for example – the usage of `int`, which in .NET is `System.Int32`, is being replaced by the usage of `nint`, which enables the compiler to compile the code to either x64 or x32.

But what about code that is being shared with other applications, let's say an Android app. As far as I am aware `nint` etc. are only available for iOS and OS X, so one must use `int` in that shared code again.

Concrete example could be a PCL, that is linked to a Xamarin.iOS app.

What happens to

```
int Add(int one, int two)
{
    return one + two;
}
```

from the PCL, when being used within the iOS app?

Comment: nint is ONLY for iOS and Mac projects. So if you are writing anything in shared code or PCL you would just use the code you listed. When you call it from iOS it is just an int, you can of course cast it to an nint if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got it. The point is, that everything that touches native APIs needs to be prepared (by the compiler) to run in x32 or x64 mode. That is what the new types like nint are made for.

Everything that doesn't touch native stuff can still leverage the "native .NET type system" including Int32. Which answers the question of how that sample code above could work in a PCL: as that PCL code will never depend on native APIs, it's okay.

Answer (score 3):

> `int`, which in .NET is `System.Int32`, is being replaced by `nint`

That's incorrect. `int` remains and will always be a 32 bits integer.

What happens is that some of Apple API (both iOS and OSX) are using types like `NSInteger`. This type is 32bits, on 32 bits processor, and 64 bits on 64 bits processors.

That does not exists in .NET, the closest being `IntPtr` which is not an easy type to use in general.

At the time the original MonoTouch was written the world (at least the mobile world) was 32bits and the API were bounds using `System.Int32`. That worked well for years but, eventually, the 64 bits world became mobile.

This is why Xamarin introduced `nint` (and `nuint` and `nfloat`). Those types will vary by the CPU architecture. It lets us (and you) bind the API just like Apple defined them (a `int` stays an `int` but a `NSInteger` becomes an `nint`).

As for PCL (or shared code) you should **avoid** those types. They are not available on all platforms (and even if the source was copied you would be missing the JIT/AOT optimizations on them). IOW the only place it should be used is in your platform specific code (iOS and/or OSX).

Comment: My initial statement was clearly misleading, I just edited it. Of course System.Int32 is not being replaced, but the usage of it in regards of native APIs as you stated, too, is being replaced by nint. As I wrote I am aware that nint & co are only available for iOS/Mac, so the question was targeting a different topic – see also my answer.

Comment: Might link to Xamarin post like this one, http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/native_types_cross_platform/ It does clearly list what to pay attention to for PCL and Shared Projects.